# Riemann Localization Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

This theorem from PMA Rudin and one moment really excites me.

1) Let's take a look at Corollary. Let $f\equiv 0$ in some $J=(a,b)$. Then for any $x\in J$ $\exists r_x>0$ such that $(x-r_x,x+r_x)\subset J$. Then for any $t\in (-r_x,r_x)$ we get $f(x+t)-f(x)=0$ and in this case we can take $M=1$. Theorem $8.14$ follows that $\lim \limits_{N\to \infty}s_N(f;x)=0$ for every $x\in J$. Is my reasoning correct?

2) Rudin gives another formulation of this corollary but one moment seems to me strange. Why $s_N(f;x)-s_N(g;x)\to 0$ only in point in $x$? 
By virtue of corollary we have $s_N(f;t)-s_N(g;t)\to 0$ for any $t$ which are in some neightborhood $x$. Right?

Because let $h(t)=f(t)-g(t)$ then $h(t)=0$ for all $t$ in some neightborhood of $x$, then $s_N(f;t)-s_N(g;t)\to 0$ for any $t$ which are in some neightborhood $x$.

Comment: What you say makes sense.

Comment: @ForgotALot, And what did you think about it?

Comment: I thought that it made sense (i.e., seemed mathematically correct, to the extent my limited knowledge can discern that).

Comment: You think that my reasoning is incorrect?