# Convergence of Fourier series in $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $f$ equals $-1$ on $[-\pi, 0]$ and $+1$ on $(0, \pi)$. Prove that $S_{N} f(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ if $x \in(-\pi, 0) \cup(0, \pi)$ and that
$$
\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} S_{N} f(0)=0
$$
where we define $S_{N}$ :
$$
\begin{array}{c}
S_{N} f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \sum_{|n| \leq N} c_{n} e^{i n x} \\
c_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int f(y) e^{-i n y} d y
\end{array}
$$
I think I was able to show the second part and I find $S_{N} f(0)=0$ for every $N$!

But for the first part I have some problems to show the pointwise convergence. I know the theorem in the link [pointwise convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582156/pointwise-convergence-of-fourier-series-from-rudin) But I dont know that we can use it for this problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is differentiable at $x,$ then $S_N(f,x)\to f(x).$ You can derive this by using the Dirichlet kernel representation of $S_N(f,x).$